# How to convert date format using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am very new to javascript, how to convert date format('2016/5/6') to ('06.05.2015'). I want to convert in it because i need to manipulate date. But only ('06.05.2015') format are used everywhere.
Please suggest me any link or tutorial

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var today = new Date('2016/5/6');
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'.'+dd+'.'+yyyy;
alert(today);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/erj8jq53/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date('2016/5/6');
var d = date.getDate();
if(d < 10) d = "0" + d;

var m = (date.getMonth()+1);
if(m < 10) m = "0" + m;

var y = date.getFullYear();

console.log(d+"."+m+"."+ y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#337cbff5ec2603c4e59ef8843d76712b

```js
var currentTime = new Date(),
    month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1,
    date = currentTime.getDate(),
    year = currentTime.getFullYear();

document.querySelector('[data-action=leftdate]').innerHTML = month + '.' + date + '.' + year;
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span data-action="leftdate"></span>
```